# ImageDataGenerator does not perform specified transformations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have defined following training image data generator:

```
train_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                                  rescale = 1./255,
                                  rotation_range = 25,
                                  zoom_range=[0.8, 1.2],
                                  vertical_flip=True,
                                  horizontal_flip=True,
                                  )

train_data_gen = train_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=raw_images_training_dir,
                                  class_mode="categorical",
                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                  shuffle=True,
                                  target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
                                  color_mode="grayscale")
```

But whenever I try to access one of its batches it seems that specified transformations (such as rescale) were not performed. For example, by executing following code:

```
images, labes = next(train_data_gen)
print(image[0].max())
```

I get 202.64307 as maximum pixel size. It is like generator has not rescaled data even though I've specified it above. Any thoughts?

Comment: everything looks OK to me.  You might try saving the transformed images to a directory and then take a look at them.  In  flow_from_directory set parameter save_to_dir to a directory on your machine. Documentation is at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Comment: You are printing ```image[0].max()``` whereas logically you should try printing ```images[0].max()```. Image might be an entirely different variable in your code.